# For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f_n(x)= \frac{1}{n} \sin{nx}$. Each $f_n$ is a differentiable function. Show these two statements are true?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

(a) $\lim{f_n(x)}=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,

(b) $\lim{f'_n(x)}$ need not exist [at $x=\pi$ for instance.]

For part (a) I believe I can prove this using the Squeeze Theorem. However, I do not quite understand part (b), and how to prove it.

Comment: Since $f'_n(x)=\cos(nx)$, we see that when $x=\pi$ we have the sequence $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$ which alternates and diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a you have a bounded sequence being multiplied by a sequence which decreases to 0.

For part b, what is $f_n'$?